# $X=(-\infty,0]\cup\left\{{1\over n}:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ with subspace topology Then

Tags: general-topology

$X=(-\infty,0]\cup\left\{{1\over n}:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$ with subspace topology. Then

1. $0$ is an isolated point
2. $(-2,0]$ is an open set
3. $0$ is a limit point of the subset $\left\{{1\over n}:n\in\mathbb N\right\}$
4. $(-2,0)$ is open set.

$0$ is not an isolated point of $X$ as every nbd of $0$ contains a point of the form $1\over n$ so  $3$ is true and $1$ is false, $2$ is false as $0$ is not interior point, $4$ is true as every point is interior point. Am i right?

Comment: You're right.${}$

Comment: only 3 and 4 are true. by the way; 3 is not a limit point.

Comment: Then why $3$ is true?

Comment: 3 is not a limit point. but 3 is true. because 0 is a limit point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right.

3) is true as every nbd of 0 contains a point of the form $\frac 1n$.

4) is true as for any points $x\in (0,2)$, there exists an open set $U$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $x \in U \cap X \subseteq (0,2)$.